# SSL Cloud app con SHA-2

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

Buenos días, tengo un certificado creado por GoDaddy para un sitio ya generé la configuración para cargarlo a un `coudapp` en [azure](/questions/tagged/azure), este certificado posee una `thumbprintAlgorithm` `sha2`, pero en todas las guías de [azure](/questions/tagged/azure) trabaja únicamente con `sha1`, he buscado tutoriales para cambiarlo en desarrollo pero no ha sido posible.

¿Alguien podría orientarme sobre que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos, de la misma manera que tú, genere un certificado en GoDaddy y escogí `sha2` como `thumbprintAlgorithm`, ya que según GoDaddy pronto dejarán de utilizar `sha1`:

> Los nuevos certificados que emitimos con la fecha de vencimiento a
>   partir del 1 de enero de 2017, solo podrán usar SHA-2. Otros
>   certificados nuevos deberán de usar SHA-2 asimismo.
>
> Los certificados de firma codificada con fecha de vencimiento
>   posterior al 31 de diciembre de 2015, también deberán de usar SHA-2.

[Referencia](https://es.godaddy.com/help/informacion-sobre-el-requisito-de-la-funcion-criptografica-sha-2-4818)

Una vez obtuve los certificados, GoDaddy genero los descargables para `IIS`, que es el servidor web que utilizar microsoft. Con estos descargables y la utilidad de administrador de certificados de [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), pude generar el `.pfx` y subirlo a [azure](/questions/tagged/azure).

Acá esta la documentación oficial en ingles de como agregar certificados ssl a [azure](/questions/tagged/azure):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: efectivamente seguí esa guía sin ningún problema, pero cuando reviso la pagina por https esta no deja abrir ya que encuentra un error interno, gracias por la guía y respuesta :)